# List of Mobile Devices from Apple Profile Manager

Tags: mdm, osx-server, apple-profile-manager

I have an Apple Profile Manager server with several devices enrolled (iPads, iPhones). The server can be accessed via web interface (e.g.: https://macserver.local/profilemanager).

How can I get the enrolled mobile devices without web crawling?
Is there any web-service/ api that could be used? (couldn't find any)

Thanks in advance and have a great week forwards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Victor. Your given path lead me to the database (PostgreSQL)

To access the ProfileManager database:

```
sudo -u _devicemgr psql -h /Library/Server/ProfileManager/Config/var/PostgreSQL -d devicemgr_v2m0
```

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to this, found this as well. Use this to access the database tested on server 5.6.1 and macOS 10.13

```
sudo -u _devicemgr psql -h /Library/Server/ProfileManager/Config/var/PostgreSQL devicemgr_v2m0
```

Source : [Access Profile Manager Database](https://tech.lkrms.org/under-the-hood-os-x-servers-profile-manager/)

Answer (score 2):

Apple Profile Manager is a Ruby on Rails app. You can find it here:
/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/share/devicemgr/backend/

I believe, it is configured to store all info in a sqlite database.

And there are multiple ways how you can get data out of sqlite DB.